# UMDF 2.0 Driver is not getting Deployed manually when tried with Devcon.exe

Tags: umdf, devcon

Good Morning!

I am working on UMDF2.0 driver using VisualStudio 2019, on Windows 10, using WDK .

With documentation provided by Microsoft to create Generic UMDF2.0 driver, I have created it using VS2019. On building the code, I get the .dll, .inf and .cert files are generated.

When tried to deploy the .dll file with .inf file in the target system, I am not able to deploy it manually using the Command: devcon.exe install UMDFDriver1.inf Root/UMDFDriver1.dll

I see the following output after executing the command:

Device node created. Install is complete when drivers are installed...
Updating drivers for Root\UMDFDriver1.dll from C:\Users\Mahaboob A Aslam\Desktop\New folder (7)\UMDFDriver1.inf.

devcon.exe failed.

I am doing it as per the documentation given by the Microsoft docs.

When i try to debug the Generic UMDF2.0 driver using VS2019, following the Microsoft Docs,
The debug control does not come into the source code, whereas it goes into the Machine instruction code.

Note:

===========================================

## I forgot to add the .inf file , below is content of UMDFDriver.inf file

```
`;

; UMDFDriver1.inf

;

[Version]

Signature="$Windows NT$"

Class=Sample ; TODO: edit Class

ClassGuid={78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171} ; TODO: edit ClassGuid

Provider=%ManufacturerName%

CatalogFile=UMDFDriver1.cat

DriverVer= ; TODO: set DriverVer in stampinf property pages

PnpLockDown=1

[Manufacturer]

%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NT$ARCH$

[Standard.NT$ARCH$]

%DeviceName%=MyDevice_Install, Root\UMDFDriver1 ; TODO: edit hw-id

[ClassInstall32]

AddReg=SampleClass_RegistryAdd

[SampleClass_RegistryAdd]

HKR,,,,%ClassName%

HKR,,Icon,,"-10"

[SourceDisksFiles]

UMDFDriver1.dll=1

[SourceDisksNames]

1 = %DiskName%

; =================== UMDF Device ==================================

[MyDevice_Install.NT]

CopyFiles=UMDriverCopy

[MyDevice_Install.NT.hw]

[MyDevice_Install.NT.Services]

AddService=WUDFRd,0x000001fa,WUDFRD_ServiceInstall

[MyDevice_Install.NT.CoInstallers]

AddReg=CoInstallers_AddReg

[MyDevice_Install.NT.Wdf]

UmdfService=UMDFDriver1,UMDFDriver1_Install

UmdfServiceOrder=UMDFDriver1

[UMDFDriver1_Install]

UmdfLibraryVersion=$UMDFVERSION$

ServiceBinary=%12%\UMDF\UMDFDriver1.dll

[WUDFRD_ServiceInstall]

DisplayName = %WudfRdDisplayName%

ServiceType = 1

StartType = 3

ErrorControl = 1

ServiceBinary = %12%\WUDFRd.sys

[CoInstallers_AddReg]

HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WUDFCoinstaller.dll"

[DestinationDirs]

UMDriverCopy=12,UMDF ; copy to drivers\umdf

[UMDriverCopy]

UMDFDriver1.dll

; =================== Generic ==================================

[Strings]

ManufacturerName="<Your manufacturer name>" ;TODO: Replace with your manufacturer name

ClassName="Samples" ; TODO: edit ClassName

DiskName = "UMDFDriver1 Installation Disk"

WudfRdDisplayName="Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework Reflector"

DeviceName="UMDFDriver1 Device"`
```

Please help me out in 1) Deploying the driver with the Devcon.exe
2) Procedure to follow with the detail steps to debug the code
I would be thankful to you if assisted for the following above two points.

Regards

Mahaboob A Aslam

I tried all the ways that were given in the Microsoft documentation